# Python find similar sequences in string

Tags: python, python-2.7, text, difflib

I want a code to return sum of all similar sequences in two string. I wrote the following code but it only returns one of them

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
a='Apple Banana'
b='Banana Apple'
def similar(a,b):
    c = SequenceMatcher(None,a.lower(),b.lower()).get_matching_blocks()
    return sum( [c[i].size if c[i].size>1 else 0 for i in range(0,len(c)) ] )
print similar(a,b)
```

and the output will be

```
6
```

I expect it to be: 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`get_matching_blocks()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) returns the longest contiguous matching subsequence. Here the longest matching subsequence is 'banana' in both the strings, with length 6. Hence it is returning 6.

Try this instead:

```
def similar(a,b):
    c = 'something' # Initialize this to anything to make the while loop condition pass for the first time
    sum = 0

    while(len(c) != 1):
        c = SequenceMatcher(lambda x: x == ' ',a.lower(),b.lower()).get_matching_blocks()

        sizes = [i.size for i in c]
        i = sizes.index(max(sizes))
        sum += max(sizes)

        a = a[0:c[i].a] + a[c[i].a + c[i].size:]
        b = b[0:c[i].b] + b[c[i].b + c[i].size:]

    return sum
```

This "subtracts" the matching part of the strings, and matches them again, until `len(c)` is 1, which would happen when there are no more matches left.

However, this script doesn't ignore spaces. In order to do that, I used the suggestion from [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16431964/ignore-spaces-when-comparing-strings-in-python): just preprocess the strings before you pass them to the function like so:

```
a = 'Apple Banana'.replace(' ', '')
b = 'Banana Apple'.replace(' ', '')
```

You can include this part inside the function too.

Comment: Tried to set `a='Apple Banana Orange'` & `b='Orange Banana Apple'`, then get a result `13`?

Comment: I have updated my answer to handle more general cases, including the one that you mentioned. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: if you move 
sizes = [i.size for i in c]
    i = sizes.index(max(sizes)) 
inside while loop it works better

Comment: Whoops! That was a mistake I made when copying the lines to SO. Thanks for the heads up. I've updated my answer.

Comment: you should use get_longest_match and subtract that segment, instead

Answer (score 0):

When we edit your code to this it will tell us where 6 is coming from:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
a='Apple Banana'
b='Banana Apple'
def similar(a,b):
    c = SequenceMatcher(None,a.lower(),b.lower()).get_matching_blocks()
    for block in c:
        print "a[%d] and b[%d] match for %d elements" % block
print similar(a,b)
```

> a[6] and b[0] match for 6 elements
>
> a[12] and b[12] match for 0 elements

Answer (score 0):

I made a small change to your code and it is working like a charm, thanks @Antimony

```
def similar(a,b):
    a=a.replace(' ', '')
    b=b.replace(' ', '')

    c = 'something' # Initialize this to anything to make the while loop condition pass for the first time
    sum = 0
    i = 2
    while(len(c) != 1):
        c = SequenceMatcher(lambda x: x == ' ',a.lower(),b.lower()).get_matching_blocks()
        sizes = [i.size for i in c]
        i = sizes.index(max(sizes))
        sum += max(sizes)
        a = a[0:c[i].a] + a[c[i].a + c[i].size:]
        b = b[0:c[i].b] + b[c[i].b + c[i].size:]
    return sum
```